# Is a mutex always held by a thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

A mutex is acquired by a thread if this thread wants to access the critical area.

But before the thread tries to access this area, is the mutex (if it has never been used before) "free" or is the mutex always held by a thread?

Comment: Nothing stops you from building a mutex that starts in a "locked" state, it just doesn't make sense since mutex is already a very specialized synchronization object. For example semaphores can start in a "locked" state and in fact this is very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutex can be "free" (i.e. unlocked). Only an unlocked mutex can be locked (acquired) by a thread.

Furthermore a *pthread mutex* can be created as a global variable with static storage duration, initialized with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZE` - this kind of mutex object is actually created at "*compile time*" and of course there is no threads that could hold it from there...

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and explaining it to me. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If no thread locks the mutex, which by default is the case, the mutex can be considered as "free" in your words.

So to answer your question, no, the mutex doesn't always have to be held. And upon creation it won't have a thread holding it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Your help was very appreciated.